# Difference between cheap and expensive HDMI cables in terms of performance?

Tags: hdmi, cable

I happened to wander around John Lewis's electronics sections yesterday (for the uninitiated it's a chain of upmarket department stores in the UK) and I came across an ["ultra-fast" HDMI cable](http://www.johnlewis.com/monster-900-hdmi-cable-1m/p231743937), 1 metre long that retailed for 59.99 pounds (or about 94 dollars). Only recently I bought a 2 metre-long HDMI cable for 2.99 (or about 4.70 dollars) that I have been perfectly happy with.

Is there any practical difference? I mean the price difference is just staggering, what more could I possibly get by shelling out for such an expensive HDMI cable apart from possibly better coating and that swivel adapter? Are these cables really faster and in what respect?

Comment: The full answer :) [here](http://www.tested.com/tech/3329-the-difference-between-cheap-and-expensive-hdmi-cables/)

Answer (score 1):

As long as it works, none.

With analogue cabling quality matters, noise = distortion. With digital cabling(signalling) it either works or it doesnt, you dont get minor distortions. I buy my HDMI cables in the €2 store (like a poundshop). Monster and the like are just scamming idiots with €200 "gold plated" cabling.